# how to calculate the performed permutations of elements and display the sorting process of Quicksort in c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I am a newbie in quicksort algorithm and I wanted to count swap and output the process of it(display the intermediate states of the array being sorted after each performed permutation.). Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


void print(const int a[])
{
    for(int i=0;i < 10; i++) {
    cout << setw(3) << a[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int Partition( int *A , int start , int end )
{
     int pivot = A[end]; 
     int partitionIndex = start; 

     int i = start;
 while ( i < end ){ 
    if( A[i] < = pivot ){
        swap ( A[i], A[partitionIndex] );
        partitionIndex++; 
    }
    i ++ ;
    print(A); //something wrong here?
}
    swap( A[partitionIndex], A[end]);
    return partitionIndex;  
}
```

Here is my recursion function

```
void QuickSort( int *A , int start , int end ){
        if( start < end ){
           int partitionIndex = Partition( A , start , end );
            QuickSort( A , start , partitionIndex - 1 );
            QuickSort( A , partitionIndex + 1 , end );
 }
```

The main function

```
int main(){
     int n = 10;
     int *A = new int[n]; 

     for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++ ){
         cin >> A[i];
     }
     cout<<endl;

  QuickSort( A , 0 , n - 1 ); 
  for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
    cout << A[i] <<" "; 
  }
  delete []A;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of Quicksort that prints what it is doing.  It highlights in a certain colour the items an activity uses:

- yellow is used when two items are compared
- red is used when two items are swapped
- green is used to show where the pivot ends up

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using std::cout;
using std::setw;

void print(const char *prefix, const int a[], const int color, const int left, const int right, const int start, const int end, const int size)
{
    cout << setw(20) << prefix << " ";
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (i >= start && i <= end)
        {
            if (i == left || i == right)
                cout << " \x1b[1m\x1b[" << color << "m" << setw(3) << a[i] << "\x1b[0m";
            else
                cout << " \x1b[0m" << setw(3) << a[i];
        }
        else
            cout << setw(4) << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

int swaps = 0;

void swap(int A[], const int left, const int right, const int start, const int end, const int size)
{
    if (left == right)
        return;

    print("Swapping:", A, 31, left, right, start, end, size);

    int temp = A[left];
    A[left]  = A[right];
    A[right] = temp;

    swaps++;
}

int partition(int A[], const int start, const int end, const int size)
{
    int pivot = A[end];
    int partitionIndex = start;
    
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        print("Comparing:", A, 33, i, end, start, end, size);
        if (A[i] < pivot)
            swap(A, i, partitionIndex++, start, end, size);
    }

    swap(A, partitionIndex, end, start, end, size);
    return partitionIndex;
}

void quicksort(int A[], const int start, const int end, const int size)
{
    if (start > end)
        return;

    cout << "\n";
    print("About to sort:", A, 0, -1, -1, start, end, size);

    if (start == end)
        return;

    int p = partition(A, start, end, size);
    print("Partitioned:", A, 32, p, p, start, end, size);

    quicksort(A, start, p-1, size);
    quicksort(A, p+1, end, size);
}        

int main()
{
    int A[] = { 7, 2, 9, 1, 8, 4, 6, 3, 10, 5 };
    quicksort(A, 0, 9, 10);

    cout << "\n";
    print("Sorted:", A, -1, -1, -1, 0, 9, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/BJJ-9IXGd

In case your environment doesn't understand ANSI escape sequences, here is a variant that displays similar info but doesn't use them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using std::cout;
using std::setw;

void print(const char *prefix, const int a[], const int start, const int end, const int size)
{
    cout << setw(20) << prefix << " {";
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        if (i >= start && i <= end)
            cout << (i == 0 ? "" : ",") << setw(3) << a[i];
        else
            cout << (i == 0 ? "" : ",") << setw(3) << " ";
    cout << "}\n";
}

void print_swap(const char *prefix, const int a[], const int left, const int right, const int size)
{
    cout << setw(20) << prefix << " {";
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        if (i == left || i == right)
            cout << (i == 0 ? "" : ",") << setw(3) << a[i];
        else
            cout << (i == 0 ? "" : ",") << setw(3) << " ";
    cout << "}\n";
}

int swaps = 0;

void swap(int A[], const int left, const int right, const int size)
{
    if (left == right)
        return;
        
    print_swap("Swapping:", A, left, right, size);

    int temp = A[left];
    A[left]  = A[right];
    A[right] = temp;

    swaps++;
}

int partition(int A[], const int start, const int end, const int size)
{
    int pivot = A[end];
    int partitionIndex = start;
    
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        print_swap("Comparing:", A, i, end, size);
        if (A[i] < pivot)
            swap(A, i, partitionIndex++, size);
    }

    swap(A, partitionIndex, end, size);
    return partitionIndex;
}

void quicksort(int A[], const int start, const int end, const int size)
{
    if (start > end)
        return;

    cout << "\n";
    print("About to sort:", A, start, end, size);

    if (start == end)
        return;

    int p = partition(A, start, end, size);
    print("Partition:", A, p, p, size);
    print("Partitioned:", A, start, end, size);

    quicksort(A, start, p-1, size);
    quicksort(A, p+1, end, size);
}        

int main()
{
    int A[] = { 7, 2, 9, 1, 8, 4, 6, 3, 10, 5 };
    quicksort(A, 0, 9, 10);

    cout << "\n";
    print("Sorted:", A, 0, 9, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/rktvKUQfd